# Unity, gnome-shell and Cinnamon don't have their top panel after removing Lubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, cinnamon

Using Ubuntu 12.04. First it came with Unity, then with a zeal of trying other Desktop Environments and I have installed GNOME-shell and no conflicts, works fine. Then I have gone through Lubuntu and Xubuntu as well. But some panel problem started with Lubuntu raised and I have removed Lubuntu DE from my PC.

But that thing got conflicted with my Unity, GNOME and Cinnamon & they are not working. These three are **not having only of their Panels**. I just see any **empty desktop**. Currently only KDE and Xfce can run fine with my Ubuntu 12.04. But I want to get back with Unity, GNOME and Cinnamon also.

This is how my desktop look like [image]

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. This will reinstall the unity, and then possibly any other gnome derivative will run normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this bug as well.  The only way I have been able to fix this is by deleting my ~/.config folder.
A better option is to simply move your .config folder into another folder

```
mv -f ~/.config ~/.backupconfig
```

in case you are unfamiliar with terminal commands:

'mv' is the move command and '-f' forces the move

This will return Unity to normal and allow you to use it again, though you will have to set up your Launcher panel again.  I have yet to find a way to use both together, unfortunately, because I really like Lubuntu and Unity.  I hope problems will be resolved when LXQt is finished and Unity migrates to Qt.  I think the problems arise mainly from openbox, and some sort of conflicting config there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you have installed/uninstalled any of these desktop environments, but you might want to try to reinstall/uninstall such things using `tasksel`.

`sudo apt-get install tasksel`

Then run:

`sudo tasksel`

This will give you a list of the complete packages and desktop environments. Just select what you want by navigating up and down the list with your arrow keys, and select a package with the space bar. For example, if you select and installed the `Xubuntu Desktop` it will install the entire Xubuntu desktop, configured with all packages and software, on your system. If you want it removed, it'll remove all of it.

Try installing the `Ubuntu Desktop` package through `tasksel`, it might reinstall any missing or broken packages and configurations for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering but as I've seen in tasksel ubuntu desktop already installed .

Comment: In `sudo apt-get install taskel` you need to make it `tasksel`.