# can;t view desktop items when switching from gnome to unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, desktop-environments

did a basic 14.04 installation . 
after a while installed gnome 3.10

switched to unity again by selecting from setting icons at Gnome login

Everything is working fine Except Now I cant view any icons on the desktop or the wallpaper 
Only A dull grey desktop of Gnome is visible

What can I Do to fix this issue

Comment: does running `nautilus` in command line while in unity bring it all back ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a tentative (if not wholly perfect) solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191556/unity-gnome-shell-and-cinnamon-dont-have-their-top-panel-after-removing-lubunt?rq=1).

Basically what I did was to install tasksel: `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

Then run it: `sudo tasksel`

Then deselect (using the space key) the entry "Ubuntu GNOME Desktop" and select "OK".

It then uninstalled a host of packages, including some programs that I didn't expect it to, and that I use on a daily basis (like Anki), but when I rebooted the computer, the interface was back to normal. Use at your own risk! :)