# Unity desktop broke after installing GNOME

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I'm running 14.04. I've already got half way there. I've reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`, but my actual desktop is still not working. No icons displayed, can't right click or drag, same wallpaper as login screen (with the little Ubuntu watermark at the bottom), and in the top left corner it says nothing (should say Ubuntu Desktop). Ive already removed GNOME, reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`, and purged/installed Nautilus, but nothing has worked.

Additionally, the gnome theme is still in the grub and boot logo. Fixing this isn't top priority, but if it can be fixed, that'd be awesome!

Comment: Unity breaks after installing Gnome Shell sounds like you are using a third party repository to install latest gnome desktop, are you?

Comment: I installed using the Ubuntu store thing originally, but then I did it from apt-get. I've removed both since though

Comment: Just checked, it was ubuntu-gnome-desktop that I install/removed from atp-get

Comment: Please consider asking a separate question regarding the issue with the logo in `grub`. It seems unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191556/unity-gnome-shell-and-cinnamon-dont-have-their-top-panel-after-removing-lubunt?rq=1).

Basically what I did was to install tasksel: `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

Then run it: `sudo tasksel`

Then deselect (using the space key) the entry "Ubuntu GNOME Desktop" and select "OK".

It then uninstalled a host of packages, including some programs that I didn't expect it to, and that I use on a daily basis (like Anki), but when I rebooted the computer, the interface was back to normal – including replacing the Gnome logo during startup (grub) and shutdown with the proper Ubuntu logo. Use at your own risk! :)